# Função printf não está sendo executada após o método scanf

Tags: c

Bem meu problema é o seguinte, tenho um programa que calcula a área de um círculo, aqui vai o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.14

int main()
{
   double radius;
   double area;

   printf("Program to calculate the are of a circle\n");
   printf("Enter the radius: ");
   scanf("%d", radius);

   area = (radius * radius) * PI;

   printf("The area is: %d", area);

   return 0;
}
```

Porém ao executá-lo, a função printf após o scanf não é executada, o que está errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto na linha do scanf é o  seguinte: "scanf("%d", &radius);"
Faltou o &, por isso ele não continua a execução, sempre que for realizar a leitura de um número deve aparecer ele na frente

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Como a já foi falado antes, para que o programa 'rode' sem erros, você precisa colocar o "&" no scanf.
Ex: scanf("%d", & nomeDaVariável);
Outra observação é referente a saída da variável.
%d ou %i = números inteiros (sem precisão de casas decimais).
%f = Valores com precisão de 6 casas decimais Ex: 35.123456.
Para controlar a quantidade de casas você tem duas opções:
1ª dentro do %f, voce coloca a precisão desejada, suponha que voce precise de um valor com precisão de duas casas decimais:
printf(" meu valor: %.2f",minhaVariavel);
a sacada é entre o '%' e o ' f ', colocar '**.**' e a quantidade de casas: '.1' , '.2', ...
2ª você faz como no exemplo abaixo e usa o %g, este configura automaticamente a saída.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

const float PI = 3.14;
int main(){
   float raio;
   double area;

printf("Programa para calcaular a area de um circulo.\n");
   printf("Digite o raio: ");
   scanf("%f", & raio);

area = PI * (raio * raio);

printf("Area = %g \n",area);
}

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente, transforma todas as variáveis em `float` e coloca um `&` no scanf
(Quando você ver ponteiros vai entender o porquê disso)

Seu `scanf` vai ficar assim:

`scanf("%f", &radius);`

That's all =)

Answer (score -2):

Tente usar `fflush(stdin);` antes do `scanf`, esse comando vai limpar o buffer de entrada, acontece do `scanf` reconhecer o `\n` que você usou anteriormente no `printf` como o enter da inserção do valor porém a variável recebe um valor vazio.